# Committee with Order: Probability that Person A is chosen as president or treasurer

Tags: probability

Question: There are 20 people to be selected for a committee of three, consisting of a president, secretary general and a treasurer. What is the probability that a particular Person $A$ will be selected as president **or** treasurer?

Could you please verify my answer?

${^{19} P_2\over ^{20} P_3}=0.05$

I'm not sure if there is supposed to be some form of adding two permutations in the answer?

Comment: If we are supposed to assume that no person can hold more than one office, then you should add the probability that person $A$ will be selected as the president to the probability that person $A$ will be selected as the treasurer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ denote the event that person A is chosen for president and let $T$ denote the event that person A is chosen for treasurer.

Then the events $P$ and $T$ are mutually exclusive so that:$$\Pr(P\cup T)=\Pr(P)+\Pr(T)=\frac1{20}+\frac1{20}=0.1$$